# Error while running the command npm run dev

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-install

I am starting to do a new application for the first time and i installed git and node.js and set the path.. With the link from bitbucket i cloned the project then i gave `npm install`.. Upto this everything was fine but when i gave `npm run dev`, it was throwing this error:

[image]

I think the issue was related to path and i don't know what to change in it. My path looks as below:

[image]

The other questions in the forums doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the first '`;`' in your `PATH` system environment variable. Check that your PATH does not end with '`;`'

Check also that [you don't have multiple value for `ComSpec`](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15891#issuecomment-284989003). ([and no semicolon](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11749#issuecomment-286325187))

Comment: Thanks for your help, But it doesn't solve my issue.. Everything was fine only as per your answer.. Kindly check with the value under ```easyplussdk``` variable is right or not?

Comment: @ManiRaj it is not, apparently: http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/easyplus-sdk-167685-program.aspx

Comment: Then which path should i add there @VonC?

Comment: @ManiRaj not sure it is a path issue. Did you change your path and open a new CMD windows? The current one would not see your changes.

Comment: Yes @VonC, I opened it in new windows and also done restart but nothing helps me..

Comment: But i think the issue is mainly with node.js.. But unable to resolve it..

Comment: @ManiRaj Maybe Git itself interfers: try just locally in your current `CMD` to set a `PATH` with the bare minimum: `set PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem`. See if nodejs works then.